# Unknown BigQuery Google Ads Data Transfer Service error: Non-manager account doesn't exist (or account is not active), so data will not be imported

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I have just tried to set up the Google Ads data transfer service for BigQuery. I followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer) and my account has the necessary permissions in both the GCP project and the Google Ads account.

The result was an error message which reads `Non-manager account doesn't exist (or account is not active), so data will not be imported.`

What is this error message and how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the person who created the transfer have necessary [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer#required_permissions) then try to recreate the transfer. If the issue persist it might be an issue with Google Ads reports or permissions and if this is the case you would need to contact their [support](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7217785?hl=en) as indicated in the [BQ documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/transfer-support)

Answer (score 1):

If the BigQuery Data Transfer was running successfully in the past, then this error probably indicates that the access token has expired. All you need to do is

1. Go to the Data Transfer Job
2. On the top right corner click More -> Update Credentials
3. Login using a Google Ads user credentials

and you should be good to go!